# microseconds epoch time parsing using strptime

Tags: epoch, strptime

I am using fluentbit for sending logs and the logs have a timestamp like:

`__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP : <micro seconds from epoch>`

example -

`__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP : 1528118184711009`

Fluentbit uses `strptime` to parse the time string. But as I see in the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) of strptime, I do not see a format string that does the parsing for microseconds from epoch or milliseconds from epoch.

I can only specify the format string in fluentbit.
I was guessing it like `"%10s"` for only taking the first 10 digits but it doesn't works.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity:

The `%s` works fine for even microseconds. It only takes the required number of digits if there is more precision given.